# How do I view a page with a different character encoding in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, encoding

I'm looking at a web page and the characters are all ASCII gibberish. I have reason to believe the web page is in Shift-JIS character encoding. So, I want to view the page in that encoding.

I'm using Firefox 29, and after much searching, both in the interface and online, I can't see how one can select to view a page in a particular character encoding. It used to just be in the `View` menu. Now... where is it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. If you press <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>, you get the old menu bar temporarily back

   [image]
2. Under `View » Character Encoding` you see "Japanese (Shift_JIS)"

   [image]

Comment: @ nixda : I'm using Firefox 62.0.2 (64-bit) on my Windows 10 machine. In "View" menu I'm getting the disabled and unclickable menu "Text Encoding". Why so? How should I change the "Text Encoding" then?

Comment: @JSLover Because FF checks if changing the character encoding has any effect for the current site. If not, it's disables. [Here is an example](https://superuser.com/a/783976) where the menu is still enabled. You can read more about it here: https://superuser.com/a/783976

Answer (score 3):

In Firefox 93+ one could fix the wrong page encoding by clicking to `View >> Repair Text Encoding` from the Menu (F10). Obviously, in the recent versions of FF, Mozilla ([Text Encoding no longer available in the Firefox menu panel](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/text-encoding-no-longer-available-firefox-menu)) has decided to remove the old way of changing the page encoding.